# edit py file and execute and save in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using mac.

In my anaconda "base" env,
I found my jupyter notebook able to edit python file, execute cell like a jupyter notebook. When saving, all cell output will be discarded and only saving the python code.

I found this very handy and useful.

However when I try to `conda env export > some.yml`, after create an conda from this yml, i find function lost.

I start to wonder that this is some configuration not reflected in the yml export by conda.

Seems this function is not natively support by any offical jupyter package.

**Does anyone have any idea how this function could be activated?**

When trying to run conda list jupyter, here is the output

```
# packages in environment at /opt/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py38_7  
jupyter-client            5.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-console           6.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              4.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab                2.1.5                      py_0  
jupyterlab_server         1.2.0                      py_0
```

Answer (score 0):

After 3 hours research,

pip install jupytext does the job.